# How to use Ethereum RPC API to swap tokens?

Tags: api, ethereum, web3js, json-rpc, binance-smart-chain

I am trying to code a client for swapping tokens through BSC chain (I really don't want to use web3 libraries) using Ethereum API. So learned some stuff from Ethereum RPC API documentation, but i can't really understand what are the steps for sending Raw Signed transaction. So here is my example payload:

```
data = {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "method": "eth_sendTransaction",
            "params": [
                {
                    'from': address,
                    'to': self.router_address,
                    'gas': hex(gas),
                    'gasPrice':  hex(gasPrice),
                    'value': hex(ETH_amount),
                    'data': query,
                    "nonce": await self.getTransactionCount(address)
                }],
            "id": _id}
```

And of course necessary header `{"Content-Type": "application/json"}`

The data field (query variable) basically was taken from [this](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x9b69f56bf0c60671dc3af9d4d5014465c9b9f7408959888398f74887bc563af0) transaction. If you scroll down, you can see the original payload, which of course was successfully processed, because the operation was created with PancakeSwap. But when i send the same (even with modified deadline parameter) i get the this:

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 1, 'error': {'code': -32000, 'message': 'unknown account'}}
```

Obvioulsy somewhere should be done signing function, but i just don't know how to make it. Can somebody help me? How do I process the data and make requests so that the swap succeeds? (From BNB to BUSD, for example - without approving step).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use web3.toChecksumAddress("address") for both your address and router address